# how to increase berkeley db cache size

Tags: python, performance, caching, python-2.7, berkeley-db

I am trying to set the cachesize in giga bytes for a bdb file. I am using the python interface for bdb. I see the underlying 'C' api for bdb has this option.

```
int DB->set_cachesize(DB *db, u_int32_t gbytes, u_int32_t bytes, int ncache);
```

But I am able to pass only one cachesize argument to the btopen function which is being interpreted as cache_size in bytes. This is restricting the max cache_size to 2GB. I would like to be able to set cache size to atleast 4gb.

Any help to be able to set/increase the cache size would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Below is the python function i am using to set the cache_size.

```
cache_size = (2*1024*1024*1024) - 1

db = bsddb.btopen(self._bdbFileName, cachesize=cache_size, flag='n')
```

Comment: You may not need to do this if you're running an operating system that has its own buffer cache.  Evaluate the performance of your application with smaller cache sizes, say, 1 GiB compared with 2 GiB.  If your OS is already caching the database file, you may find that your application performs better by letting the OS do it than if you dedicate the memory to BDB.

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with python interface of BDB. When i use c api, i really appreciate opening the bdb with an **environment** and set a lot configurations in the environment.

For example, open a bdb file with environment and the env dir is set to *~/env/*. Then put a file named **DB_CONFIG** in *~/env/* with content:

```
set_cachesize 4 0 1
```

The cachesize will be set to 4GB. No code needed.

You can check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/configuration_reference.html) for all the available configurations in **DB_CONFIG**.